# How to pass a variable from js file to a .vue file

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

hey am new to vuejs and am using firebase for authentication. Here is my firebase code in a separate js file. I have all mutations, state, actions and getters in this js file which is then being called into different components

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

export default {
state: {
  loggedInUser:
  localStorage.getItem("userInfo") != null
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
    : null,
  loading: false,
  error: null
},
getters: {
  loggedInUser: state => state.loggedInUser,
  loading: state => state.loading,
  error: state => state.error
},
mutations: {
  setUser(state, data) {
  state.loggedInUser = data;
  state.loading = false;
  state.error = null;
},
setLogout(state) {
  state.loggedInUser = null;
  state.loading = false;
  state.error = null;
},
setLoading(state, data) {
  state.loading = data;
  state.error = null;
},
setError(state, data) {
  state.error = data;
  state.loggedInUser = null;
  state.loading = false;
},
clearError(state) {
  state.error = null;
 }
},
actions: {
  login({ commit }, data) {
    commit("clearError");
    commit("setLoading", true);
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
      .then(user => {
        const newUser = { uid: user.user.uid };
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(newUser));
        commit("setUser", { uid: user.user.uid });
        console.log("userInfo");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
      localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
      commit("setError", error);
    });

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {

    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      let email = user.email;
    } else {
      // User is signed out.
    }
   });
},
signUserUp({ commit }, data) {
  commit("setLoading", true);
  commit("clearError");
  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
    .then(user => {
      commit("setLoading", false);

      const newUser = {
        uid: user.user.uid
      };
      console.log(newUser);
      localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(newUser));
      commit("setUser", newUser);

    })
    .catch(error => {
      commit("setLoading", false);
      commit("setError", error);
      localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
      console.log(error);
    });
},
 signOut({ commit }) {
     firebase
    .auth()
    .signOut()
    .then(
      () => {
        localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
        commit("setLogout");
      },
      _error => { }
    );
  }
 }
};
```

i am calling it in the component like this

```
import { mapGetters, mapActions, mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  components: {
  },

  data()  {
    return {,
      email: "",
    };
   },

 computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getSideBarToggleProperties"]),
    ...mapState(['loggedInUser']) 
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
    "signOut",
    "login"
    ]),

   getLogin () {
      this.login({ email: this.email });   
   },
```

I am then calling the method 'getLogin 'using @click to display like this

```
<a class="dropdown-item" id="testing">{{loggedInUser}}</a>
```

Comment: This is a very broad question and, depending on the architecture of your app, there may be several possible solutions, e.g. vuex store, props, etc... I would suggest you read some of the articles found by the following search https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=vue+js+passing+data+between+components. In case you encounter specific problems with one of the possible approaches, you may adapt your question with more details.

Comment: I think you wanted to import a js file into your vue file? and access returned values from the js file?

Answer (score 0):

export the email from the js file then import them from your vue component -inside the script tag- and then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

```
// messages.js file
const variableToUseInVue = "hello from a js file"
export default { variableToUseInVue }
```

Now in your component:

```
// Hello.vue component
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Message: {{ messages.variableToUseInVue }}</p>
    <!-- Message: hello from a js file -->
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import messages from './messages' // Import from the js location
  export default {
    data: () => ({ messages: messages })
  }
</script>
```

A second way is exporting each variable and using object destructuring:

```
// messages.js file
export const variableToUseInVue = "hello from a js file"
```

Now in your component:

```
// Hello.vue component
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Message: {{ variableToUseInVue }}</p>
    <!-- Message: hello from a js file -->
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import { variableToUseInVue } from './messages' // Import from the js location
  export default {
    data: () => ({ messages: variableToUseInVue })
  }
</script>
```

Taking in account your requirement, a better approach is to have the login function in Vuex and the user info on it, that way you have access to the information anywhere.

Also, you can have a login component which exposes the email variable and run the login function, the email variable will be reactive and will be updated on change.

Comment: Hey i tried the first approach and it works well , but the function i mentioned above is already in export default. I dont know much about vuejs, so how would i go about it?

Comment: Ok, can you share the whole file in your question please? that way I will see how is being used the function.

Comment: Hey i have updated the code in the question, pls take a look

Comment: are you using Vuex?

Comment: no , im using vuejs for the first time, i am using a template from online where vuex is used in the sign In page , but i dont know exactly how to use it

Comment: Ok, well before continue, let's see the more code, do you have the store implementation? I mean the state and the mutations, and how are you adding it to Vue. If you are not using Vuex properly, then we need to fix the store first and move on to the functionality, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62265815/returning-data-from-store-js-in-vuejs-returns-typeerror/62267031#62267031) you can see a basic example about how to use Vuex.

Comment: hey so i went through the example you gave and got stuck, i have edited the question to include the component code where im calling vuex, could you take a look and see where i went wrong?

Comment: Sure, please share the whole store code, I mean the state and the mutations, if you only have actions, it would not work. If you are using one file for mutations, state, actions and getters, then you must have a state.js or index.js file, a mutations.js file, an actions.js and a getters.js file, otherwise, you must have them in one whole file, after see the first code snippet in your question, I guess it is the actions.js file. but please, share the whole store.

Comment: Hey, i have posted the whole code in the original post, please take a look

Comment: Where are you registering or creating the Vuex store uusing `new Vuex.store`

Comment: I tried adding like in the example u gave, but the page would not render. Im assuming because there is already a export in the page not sure. But in this template, the sign In.vue and SignUp.vue work without any store and it calls from this same js file

Comment: So, how are you using mutations, actions and Vuex stuff without vuex?

Comment: What about creating a jsfiddle to see your code and help you properly? it will helpful

Comment: No, we are using mutations etc, here is a fiddle of what the vue file with the js file  - https://jsfiddle.net/advaitvarma/Lv4qnwf7/2/  . Im sorry this is my first time making  a fiddle so if anything is bad, pls ignore.

Comment: Here is the problem, state, mutations, getters and actions belongs to Vuex, not vue, to implement this properly, first you need to use vuex properly, by using the example in my previous comment, there is the main.js setting, the store setting, and how to import mapMutations, mapActions, etc. Otherwise, your code will not work, state, mutations, and other stuff are not Vue hooks, data, computed, methods are avalaible in vue.