# Returning data from store.js in vuejs returns TypeError

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a store.js file which sends an api request and gets responses using axios,
the api is tested and working perfectly.
store.js contains this code :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';
import cUser from './modules/User';
import UI from './modules/UI';
Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
    data: function () {
        return {
          responsedata: []
        };
      },
viewresults: async (commit, payload)=>{
            let token =localStorage.getItem('token');
            let username= payload.username;
            await axios.post('search',{token, username}).then(response => {
               this.responsdata = response.data;
            }).catch(er=>{
                    console.log(er);
                });
```

and i have this function in other file that uses it :

```
search(){
          console.log('search clicked');
          console.log(this.username);
          this.responsedata = this.$store.dispatch('viewresults',{
            username: this.username,
          });
          console.log(this.responsedata);
          },
    }
```

but i get this error in the browser console  :

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'responsedata' of undefined

it seems like that **viewresult** in the store.js can't see the responsedata variable defined in data return function .

Comment: you're trying to handle an async return as sync result ... if the axios post takes 5sec to perform, how do you want to know the result in the next line? use `await` and return data correctly, or simply populate the store, and use the getters, they will show soon they have something

Comment: You have a typo: change `this.responsdata = response.data;` to `this.responsedata = response.data;`, if it works, fine, else, I recommend you to change the way you are using the store. To update the data state you have to use mutations.

Comment: @balexandre can you explain more , i am using `await` in the `axios.post` so how can i return the data correctly?.
and how can i populate the store and use the getters?
i am new to vue and JS so i need some explainations.

Comment: first, you should use [Vuex store correctly](https://itnext.io/vuex-made-simple-getting-started-6bf229d432cf), secondly, you shouldn't return the data, just add to the store state and create a `computed` property to read that data, `computed` properties update them selfs when their data change. If you really need to get the data from the dispatch, you need to `return await axios.post('search', ...` and also make sure you return back the new data with `return response.data`  then in your method, `this.responsedata = await this.$store.dispatch(...)`

Comment: @AndresForonda i have fixed the typo and it is the same. i will try to see how mutations work and get back to you .

Comment: try to use vuex like intended: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/, not like a vue component :)

Comment: @balexandre this worked perfectly <3 , thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you an example about how to use the Vuex store:

```
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import store from '@/store/index';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  components: {
    App
  },
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Now the store.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
  responseData: []
}

const mutations = {
  setResponse(state, data) {
    state.responseData = data;
  }
}

const actions = {
  async viewResults({ commit }, payload) {
    let token =localStorage.getItem('token');
    let username= payload.username;
    await axios.post('search', { token, username }).then(response => {
      commit('setResponse', response.data);
    }).catch(er=>{
      console.log(er);
    });
  }
}

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
});
```

And a component to call the action and show the information:

```
// SearchAndShowData.vue component

<template>
  <div>
    <button click="search">
      Search
    </button>

    {{ responseData}}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import {mapActions, mapState} from 'vuex';
  export default {
    name: "SearchAndShowData",
    data: () => ({
      username: "Andres",
    }),
    computed() {
      // Expose the state.responseData object as responseData
      ...mapState(['responseData']) // If you want to preprocess the data, use create a getter and use mapGetters
      // As a computed property, it will be updated always that responseData has any change
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(["viewResults"]), // Expose the viewResults action as a method, call it with this.viewResults
      search() {
        this.viewResults({username: this.username })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I didn't test it, but this is the idea behind a vuex store and how to use it, if somebody sees an error, please let me know to update the answer (thanks).

Hope you can update your code with this information and it can work properly.

Also, Scrimba has a free course that could help you to extend your knowledge about Vuex, check it [here](https://scrimba.com/p/pnyzgAP/cMPa2Uk)

Comment: Thanks, i've solved my problem with adding async and await to my dispatch method as mentioned by @balexandre in previous comment, but i read about computed and mutations, and your answer seems ok.
i didn't test it but it satisfies the requirements, so i will mark your answer as correct so other people can see it.

Comment: No problem, Great to know that your request is working!